# How to draw none fuzzy/blurry line in DrawingImage/DrawingContext?

Tags: wpf

See the image.  I would like the middle line to be a crispy 1 pixel line.
You can copy and paste the sample markup into [kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) .

[alt text http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1704/lines.png](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1704/lines.png)

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Image SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="None">
      <Image.Source>
         <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
               <DrawingGroup>
                  <GeometryDrawing>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="1"/>
                     </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="50,0"/>
                     </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                  </GeometryDrawing>
                  <GeometryDrawing>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="1"/>
                     </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,5.860" EndPoint="50,5.860"/>
                     </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                  </GeometryDrawing>
                  <GeometryDrawing>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="1"/>
                     </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,12" EndPoint="50,12"/>
                     </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                  </GeometryDrawing>
               </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
         </DrawingImage>
      </Image.Source>
   </Image>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.setedgemode.aspx

```
<Image Stretch="None" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(this, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and justified my use of an Image with DrawingImage as it's Source as opposed to the DrawingBrush technique that I've typically see used for XAML icons.

Answer (score 1):

Change the middle line to:

```
<LineGeometry StartPoint="0,6" EndPoint="50,6"/>
```

You can get a crisp line on a pixel boundary by placing the line on a whole numbered unit.

Comment: I am looking for a general solution, like a flag.  I had a similar problem in CoreGraphics and the solution was to translate transform my context 0.5,0.5

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar issue with the Border control, although @phi your solution worked in most cases I also had to add the following to get it to completely work:

```
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```